# Shared link in facebook

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share

I have a facebook shared link counter.
And I now have 3 that have clicked my button, I want to know is it possible to see where the link is shared ? 
I mean in what group and so on, or can I only see 3 and thats all ?

I have tryed this link [howmanyshares](http://howmanyshares.com/) with this [link](http://codem.dk/blog/artikel/item/ungdomsspiller-i-overhalingssporet-fra-droemme-til-kollaps-det-at-skifte-klub-for-tidligt/) and here I can see 48 shares... so now I'm curious, where is the link shared. is it possible to see anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge that is not possible, **facebook** tell you who have shared your links but don't tell where they have been shared.